# Distribution of Projects

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, codeblocks, software-distribution

I am looking to release a 'sneak peak' of my project on my website, in Windows I know how to properly distribute the required files, like .dll's and such. But for Linux (Ubuntu distro) I am having trouble running my program on any other machine but my development machine. I have been able to statically link all dependancies but one

-Tiny XML
-FreeType2
-SDL
-Lua
-LuaBind
-GLU

These all have their own appropriate .a static library's. However OpenGL or lGL as I have linked it, apparently points to a .so dynamically linked library. I am unable to find a static library for OpenGL, I do understand the benefits of using Dynamically linked library's. So my question is, what is the proper process to set up a client computer to run my file? ie. How to install the dependencies (In this case only libGL.so) on their system?

I imagine I will also have to automatically chmod +x the file before it will run for them also.

Comment: "I am unable to find a static library for OpenGL" – that's because the libGL.so is part of the driver and hence **must** be dynamically loaded, if you want GPU acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a .deb file with appropriate dependencies, so a tool like synaptic can automatically take care of satisfying the dependencies.

Comment: Also, linking statically against OpenGL would be a really bad idea, because that library is strongly dependent on the graphics driver in use (unless, of course, you use the MESA software rendering library, which, however, is comparatively slow).

Comment: Thanks, I figured something along those lines but googleing it didn't bring up much info, I must have worded it inproperly.