# SDL across multiple distros

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, sdl

I just made a game with C++/SDL for linux that compiles via the help of cmake/make.

I want to distribute the game to some friends that also run linux.  Is there an easy way to help everyone install the required SDL libraries they need to run the game?

I mean..some distros use apt-get install, some use yum install, others use rpm packages (I think?)  and the sdl packages have slightly different names for each one.  Is there an easy way to have a system to install those for the people, or at least distribute what they need to install with my game?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question a while back, please try to search for an existing question before starting a new one, however here is the link[Distribution of Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326239/distribution-of-projects#comment13317741_10326239)

Comment: That question was specific to the Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: No it wasn't , the distribution I was asking about was Ubuntu, but all the linux distro's operate in somewhat the same way, you have to satisfy dependencies on the end users machine, a .deb file can actually be converted to other distros format such as redhat, it is just a different packaging format. 

In the end you need to use a program that will create for you a packing format that will either contain the needed dependencies to be installed, or retrieve them from the internet and install them.

Comment: Here is a link for debian specific packages, it shouldn't be hard for you to track down other types.

[Debian Packing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-debpkg/index.html)